# GitLab Omnibus has missing 'nginx' folder in 'etc'

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm trying to host other apps on the same server that GitLab is installed on using Ubuntu. Per some searching on [GitLab's documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#inserting-custom-nginx-settings-into-the-gitlab-server-block), I see that you can enable custom `.conf` files and direct them where they should normally live inside the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` path. The reference says to put them in that specified path, but I'm lacking the nginx folder in `/etc`. Not sure if it's intended not to be installed in `/etc`, but then why is this reference saying `nginx` should be there?

## Update 1:

Per, @bradrini's response I've managed to create the directories within `/etc/nginx/conf.d` with a configuration file named `example.conf`. The domain structure I have setup is to have GitLab at **dev.example.com** and have this other app be pointed to **test.example.com**. Below is my **nginx** configuration for this new domain:

```
server {
    # Using my actual IP here which houses GitLab and my test.example.com domain
    listen                  111.111.111.11:443 default_server ssl;

    # What the domain will be called
    server_name             test.example.com; 

    # Wildcard cert used for GitLab
    ssl_certificate         /etc/gitlab/ssl/dev.example.com.crt 

    # Wildcard key used for GitLab
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/gitlab/ssl/dev.example.com.key 

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        # Root file directory for the test.example.com domain
        root   /var/www/test.example.com/html;

        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

}
```

I am now getting no connection to my **test.example.com** domain, which is good because it was originally forwarding to my GitLab domain (dev.example.com).

I'm now thinking the issue is being caused by a nginx config problem? Is there anything else I could've missed that I should check? Do I have to worry about any `sites-enabled` or `sites-available` folders?

## Update 2:

So with my configuration above, neither my **dev.example.com** or **test.example.com** actively run. They both can't connect per my browser. Not sure what makes both of them not able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

When you install nginx, /etc/nginx/ folder is created.You can then, as you said, edit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to check /etc/nginx/conf.d/ folder.Be sure you're 'root' to be able to see everything, and check also /usr/local/nginx/ folder (they say conf files can also be there, I guess it can come from the version you install).

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be correct for the Gitlab installation process to create `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

Thankfully, the path specified in the Gitlab documentation is just an example. You can specify any directory location in the `nginx['custom_nginx_config']` configuration setting to configure nginx to search for additional configuration files.

With that in mind, you have two choices:

- uncomment the `nginx['custom_nginx_config']` line in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and use the suggested custom nginx configuration location of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`. As you have found, you will need to create the directory yourself manually via `sudo mkdir -p /etc/nginx/conf.d` before you can copy in your custom `nginx` configuration.
- or as an alternative, uncomment the value of `nginx['custom_nginx_config']` and change the value from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` to some other location you would like to store your custom nginx configuration in, for example `/opt/nginx/conf.d`. Of course, again you should manually ensure that directory actually exists and contains the nginx configuration you would like to add.

Important note: anytime the file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` is updated, don't forget to re-run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` so that your changes take affect.

Comment: Great answer @bradrini! You explain the small details that are lacking from some of the setup tutorials.... which is extremely helpful. Going to try this today and will come back here to update!

Comment: Updated the original with your implemented solution. I think we are getting somewhere, just want to make sure that my config files are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed GitLab via the Omnibus installer, the relevant files are probably expected (by your installed GitLab instance) to be under the */etc/gitlab* – not */etc/nginx* – directory.

From [Manually configuring HTTPS – NGINX settings | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#manually-configuring-https):

> Because the hostname in our example is 'gitlab.example.com', omnibus-gitlab will look for private key and public certificate files called `/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.example.com.key` and `/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.example.com.crt`, respectively. Create the `/etc/gitlab/ssl` directory and copy your key and certificate there.
>
> ```
> $ sudo mkdir -p /etc/gitlab/ssl
> $ sudo chmod 700 /etc/gitlab/ssl
> $ sudo cp gitlab.example.com.key gitlab.example.com.crt /etc/gitlab/ssl/
> ```